# Progress Bar for command line email utility (Python)

Tags: python, email, smtp

I've been developing a command line utility to send emails using the email module in python.

Everything's working fine but I really need to add a percentage based progress to show how much of the file has been uploaded, in the program. Is it possible to do so?

Given below is my code

```
message = MIMEMultipart()
message["From"] = sender_email
message["To"] = receiver_email
message["Subject"] = subject

filename = "~"

with open(filename, "rb") as attachment:
    part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(attachment.read())
  
encoders.encode_base64(part)

part.add_header(
    "Content-Disposition",
    "attachment; filename= %s" %file,
)

message.attach(part)
text = message.as_string()

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, text)
    server.close()
print("Email Sent")
```

Are there any methods in smtplib library which would help me to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: u can use tqdm python library

Comment: @ck22 I don't think the issue is deciding which progress bar library to use, but more along the lines of how to get the values to update the progressbar.

Comment: Are you going to attach very large files? I don't believe there's any facility in `smtplib` to track the upload progress. (If you want to track progress of "bulk-email send", then a ck22 points out, things like `tqdm` or `progressbar2` could be useful)

Comment: Not very large files, but ranges from 1 - 10 mb